# Trying to run linux kernel using QEMU, having trouble with boot process

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, qemu, devices

For a project, I need to be able to run an uncompressed linux kernel.  It was recommended to me to try emulating this using QEMU, since that's less involved than booting it straight on the machine.  However, I'm having trouble getting the kernel to load properly on QEMU.  I'm running on Arch Linux.

I've generated an image for it using `mkinitcpio --generate customImage3.img --kernel 5.9.1-arch1-1`.  Then, I've tried running QEMU using various combinations of command line options, the latest being:

`sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel ../kernel-build/linux-5.9.1/vmlinux -nographic -initrd customImage3.img -append "console=ttyS0" -m 512 --enable-kvm -cpu host`

I've also tried specifying a 'root' in the append section (e.g. `root=/dev/sda3`), but this doesn't change the error I get.

The output when I run QEMU is:

```
SeaBIOS (version ArchLinux 1.14.0-1)


iPXE (http://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 CA00 PCI2.10 PnP PMM+1FF912A0+1FEF12A0 CA00



Booting from ROM..mount: /proc: must be superuser to use mount.
mount: /sys: must be superuser to use mount.
mount: /dev: must be superuser to use mount.
mount: /run: must be superuser to use mount.
/init: line 13: can't open /proc/cmdline: no such file
:: running early hook [udev]
Warning: /lib/modules/5.9.1/modules.devname not found - ignoring
Failed to parse kernel command line, ignoring: No such file or directory
Starting version 246.6-1-arch
:: running hook [udev]
:: Triggering uevents...
Failed to scan subsystems: No such file or directory
Failed to scan devices: No such file or directory
ERROR: device '' not found. Skipping fsck.
:: mounting '' on real root
mount: /new_root: mount failed: Operation not permitted.
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty; job control turned off
[rootfs ]#
```

It seems that it cannot find anything it needs, like devices to boot.  I figure I must be missing some critical option, but no amount of searching is helping me figure out what I need.  Any help with this situation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in mkinitcpio: [Fix setting uid=0 gid=0 in archive](https://github.com/archlinux/mkinitcpio/pull/38)

A workaround is to call mkinitcpio with sudo.